# Polymer: Implement pagination using core-ajax

Tags: ajax, pagination, polymer

I am implementing an activity stream application, where the user can click on a "Load More" link after the initial data is loaded via core-ajax. What is the best way to load additional data when the user clicks on "Load More". Should I use an AJAX JavaScript library, or can I do that with core-ajax?

Comment: You can use `core-ajax` and just change the `url` to include `page` and `size` attributes which you can read out on the backend.

Comment: @Ümit Are core-ajax elements reusable that way?

Comment: Yup. If you use the `auto` attribute, `core-ajax`s automatically make a new request when the url changes (http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax).